# A meaningful measure of synchronicity

Tags: multivariate-analysis, large-data

I have a very large panel of data represented by the matrix elements $X_{t,k}\in\mathbb{R}$ where $t$ is a time-series index running in $1,..,T$ and $k$ is a cross-sectional index running in $1,...,N$. For each $k$ I can define a small threshold $\xi_k\in\mathbb{R}$ and I classify an observation $X_{t,k}$ as "small" if

$$\left|X_{t,k}\right|\leq \xi_k$$

My problem is to determine if **simultaneously** a large part of the $X$'s have been "small" during the time interval $[1,T]$. The most natural choice would be to consider the quantity

$$
Z = \frac{1}{T}\,\sum_{t=1}^T\prod_{k=1}^N\mathbb{1}_{\left\{\left|X_{t,k}\right|\leq \xi_k\right\}}\quad(1)
$$

where $\mathbb{1}_{\left\{\cdot\right\}}$ is the indicator function. This choice however is too drastic, it is enough that only one of the $X$'s is not small to have $Z=0$ because of the product. Any suggestions? I am looking for a proper definition of $Z$ which is smoother than the definition in (1). Note that taking

$$
Z = \frac{1}{T}\,\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N\mathbb{1}_{\left\{\left|X_{t,k}\right|\leq \xi_k\right\}}
$$

it is not interesting because in this case simultaneity is not accounted for.

Comment: Not an expert so I can't give much detail, but it sounds like you may be interested in the synchronization ratio described [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2008WR007279/abstract), and Mutual Information and Information Theory in general.

Comment: Is your choice of $\xi_k$ a pragmatic one or is this threshold of particular interest? Is there periodicity to the trends in each of the $X$ columns? Is it your goal to identify which columns of $X$ are more highly correlated than others? Is there any context you can add to the problem? Are these stocks or biological populations or is it a strictly intellectual pursuit?

Comment: Consider $\xi_k$ as given, there is no periodicity in the columns. I do not want to find a  correlation, as you mentioned it is a general definition what I am looking for (intellectual pursuit) and I want to capture simultaneity of events "$X_{t,k}$ is small".  A second possibility could be to consider 

$$Z = \frac{1}{T}\,\sum_{t=1}^T\prod_{k=1}^NK\left(\frac{\left\|X_{t,k}\right\|}{\xi_k}\right)$$

where $0<K\left(x\right)\leq 1$ is a kernel function such that $K(0)=1$ and $K(\pm\infty)=0$. However when $N$ is large the product is quite chaotic and I get a really unstable quantity.

Comment: Steven Strogatz' book *Sync: How Order Emerges From Chaos In the Universe, Nature, and Daily Life* may help you organize some thoughts around quantifying synchronicity.